# Does the Powershell command "sendkeys" work in Jenkins? If not, is there an alternative method?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to create a PowerShell script in Jenkins that input keyboard commands to test if various fields and quick key shortcuts are working.

For example, I use the following to enter a 'quick key' event that will close the application (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

```
Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{X}")
```

This works fine in powershell ise on my desktop, but when used in jenkins it returns the error:

```
Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson3939198379009014854.ps1:9 char:42
+ [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait <<<< ("%{X}")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

At first I thought this was a permissions issue, but someone suggested that Jenkins cannot run `SendKeys` because Jenkins is in non-interactive mode, and sending a key is an interaction.

Does anyone know if this is true? And if so, is there an alternative method for testing these quick keys?

For fields I can simply input a `$variable.value`, but for quick keys that don't have an input, I'm not so sure.

Comment: [Maybe related](http://howto.praqma.net/jenkins/jenkins-interactive-job).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Jenkins handle an gui/non-gui interactive python or java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14885079/1630171)